# How to replace object values with state variable react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state variable called

authInfo:

```
const [authInfo, setAuthinfo] = useState(null)
```

data is displayed like this from authInfo state:

```
{
  data:
  id:
  email:
  full_name:
  authorities: [{label: "admin", value: 1}, {label: "canEdit", value: 2}]
}
```

then I have another array.

```
const newAuthorities = [{label: 'canApprove', value 2}, {label: 'canDissaprove', value2}]
```

I would likee this to be stored in a new state variable and make a copy of the old authInfo with values replacing authorities with the newAuth Variable.

Here is the expected output

```
   {
      data:
      id:
      email:
      full_name:
      authorities: [{label: 'canApprove', value 2}, {label: 'canDissaprove', value2}]
    
    }
```

how do I replace the authorities value with the newAuthorities values in another state vaariable?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newAuthorities = [{label: 'canApprove', value 2}, {label: 'canDissaprove', value2}]
const data = {...authInfo}
data.authorities = newAuthorities
setAuthinfo(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Auth = () => {
  
  const authBase = {
    data: null,
    id: null,
    email:null,
    full_name: null,
    authorities: [{label: "admin", value: 1}, {label: "canEdit", value: 2}]
  }
  
  const newAuthorities = [{label: 'canApprove', value: 2}, {label: 'canDissaprove', value: 2}]
  
  const [authInfo, setAuthInfo] = useState(authBase)
  
  const update = () => {
    setAuthInfo({ ...authInfo, authorities: newAuthorities })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={update}>
        Update
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(authInfo, false, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};



// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Auth />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```